# Strange UICollectionViewFlowLayout overriding behaviour

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to override `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but I realized something strange. Here you can see a little code snippet:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
@end

@implementation SimpleFlowLayout

- (void)prepareLayout {
    ...
}

- (void)prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:(NSArray *)updateItems {
    ...
}

- (void)finalizeCollectionViewUpdates {
    ...
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)
     initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:
       (NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    ...
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)
     finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:
       (NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    ...
}

@end
```

As an item is added to `UICollectionView`, `reloadData` is called. `ReloadData` does always reinitialize the layout, thus it will call `prepareLayout` again and again, and will never call `prepareForCollectionViewUpdates` at all.

Do you have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: UPDATE: Solved, I had to use batchUpdate instead of reloadData in textFieldShouldReturn method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to use batchUpdate instead of reloadData in textFieldShouldReturn method.

Comment: `performBatchUpdate:completion:` is the method call for the `UICollectionView`